# How to return a custom error page in SpringBoot's asynchronous processing

Tags: java, spring

I have a question about error handling in SpringBoot.
Is there a way to display a custom error page when an exception occurs in a method annotated with @Async? 　I'd be happy to know if there is any.

We are currently implementing asynchronous processing in SpringBoot.
Asynchronous processing is outlined in the following methods.　I'm having trouble with Spring's SimpleAssyncUncaughtExceptionHandler instead of the custom ExceptionHandler catching it.

Service Class.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService {
     ...
     @Async
     public void myAsyncMethod(Intger req) throws MyException {
         if (req > 500) {
             log.error("request too large." + req);
             throw new MyException();
         }
         ...
         hogehoge(req);
     }
}
```

The ExceptionHandler class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {
     
     @ExceptionHandler
     @RespondeStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
     public ModelAndView handleMyException(MyException e) {
         log.error(e.getMessage());
         return new ModelAndView("4xx.html");
     }
}
```

MyException class (for testing)

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
}
```

Comment: Well, asynchrous processing is as the name says "asynchronous". That means the request controller won't wait for the process to finish or throw an exception (which would be synchronous) but returns immediately (meaning like "got your request and started the process"). To get the exception back to the client you'd need to either have it poll for the status or use a push message e.g. via websocket.

Comment: Having another look at your code: why don't you validate synchronously and then call another service (e.g. a worker service) for the asynchronous part?

Comment: Thank you for confirming that!
 The asynchronous service class was actually bigger (a legacy) and I wanted to add some validation to it. I rewrote the code to make it much smaller for submission to StackOverFlow, but it seems to me that it would be better to validate it in the synchronization process and do error handling there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this can be solved in part by using DeferredResult.
This was tentatively resolved by passing a DefferdResult from the Handler class and doing setErrorResult().